# Pattern matching a string against a template string

Tags: java, regex, template-engine

I have the following information

```
String templateString = "I am %NAME% and I live in %PLACE%"; 

String inputString = "I am John Doe and I live in New York";
```

I need to write a function which will take in the above 2 strings and return a HashMap of  pairs.

```
HashMap<String,String> parseInputFromTemplate(templateString, inputString) {

  // Magic 
  return result;
}
```

The result will have

```
%NAME% (key)  , John Doe (value)

%PLACE% (key) , New York (value)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem.  What if you have a legitimate % in the template String?  If you can guarantee that won't happen, this is an exercise in RegEx.

Comment: I can guarentee that % will never be part of the String. I am looking for a way to implement it using RegEx

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write the entire regex for you.  You could also split on "%".  Every other string in the resulting array would be a template var.  The others would be the static strings to discard in the inputString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract what you need.  Alternatively you can use the split() method to split on "%".   Every other string in the resulting array would be a template var. The others would be the static strings to discard in the inputString.